# What is the logic behind this scenario

Tags: c#

*This question was asked in a coding contest held recently by a major IT company. I got only 30% so I couldn't clear the contest, I thought somebody could guide me in getting the logic of this question.*

You and your friend are pilots in the Clone Army. You are facing the aerial fleet of the Separatist Droid Army. Droid planes move while maintaining a long line, so that their shields interact making it impossible to shoot down planes in the middle of the line. Thus, your only option is to keep shooting down planes at the edges of the line.

You and your friend have decided to make a game out of it. Each Droid plane has an importance level `IMP[i]`. Since the Droid planes don't advertise their importance, both of you must follow a mixed strategy and shoot down either the first plane or the last plane with `50%` chance each. If there is a single plane, the shooter with the turn will shoot it down for sure. The two of you take turns to shoot down enemy planes. You have the first turn. What is the expected sum of importance levels of planes you will shoot down?

#### Input/Output Specifications Input format:

*You will get two inputs*:

`input1 = N (1 < = N < = 1000)` is the number of Droid planes

`input2 = IMP (for 0 < = i < N , 1 < = IMP [i] < = 100)` is an array containing the importance levels of Droid planes

*Output format*:

A string containing your expected sum of importance levels of shot-down planes, rounded to exactly 3 digits after the decimal

**I tried this**

```
public static string ExpectedSum(int input1, int[] input2)
{
    //Write code here
    int droids = input1;
    Double IMP = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= droids; i++)
    {
        IMP += 0.5 * Convert.ToDouble(input2[i - 1]);
    }
    return string.Format("{0:0.000}", IMP);
    //return Convert.ToString(IMP);
}
```

Input: `2,{10,20}` Output: `15.000` This is the Explanation that they gave: There is a 50% chance that you shoot down the first plane or the second. Then, your friend will shoot down the remaining plane. Your expected sum of importance levels of shot-down planes = `0.5 * 10 + 0.5 * 20 = 15`

Comment: It's a statistics question; everything else is red herring.  Analyze the statistics and get: sum the array and divide by 2, rounded correctly to 3 decimal digits, and print the result. All other factors are statistically rolled up in the *averaging* process.

Comment: we cannot use random as it will give a different result each time, i tried but im still not getting further logic from here

Comment: the default test case they gave was 2 droids and they IMP was {10,20} and the output was 15.000

Comment: @PieterGeerkens That doesn't work for `{ 1, 4, 1 }` and I'd not want to guarantee it works for even-numbered cases.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Doesn't work for `{ 1, 4, 4, 1 }` (you have a 100% chance of getting a `1`, your teammate doesn't, so your expected scores are different).

Comment: Given the statistical character of the question, you might get better results at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Rawling: That's not how I understand the parameters os the questin. I read the spec as that each player shoots down with 100% success a droid from either the left or right end of the line, with 50% likelihood of each. Also that going first is a 50% proposition between you and your friend

Comment: @PieterGeerkens `You have the first turn` is fairly unambiguous. I agree with the first sentence of your comment.

Comment: @Rawling: Thank you.  read it through start to finish three times looking for that, and missed it every time. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution works for the example you have given, but it fails on e.g. a three-droid array as you do not have a flat `1/2` chance of shooting down each droid, but rather a `{ 3/4, 1/2, 3/4 }` chance.

I believe the following gives the correct answers, but it's very slow, so anyone else feel free to check their faster results against it.

You'd call it as `Calculate(input2, 0, input1 - 1, true)` and then round the result as you already have done.

```
static double Calculate(int[] imp, int first, int last, bool myTurn)
{
    if (first == last)
    {
        return myTurn ? imp[first] : 0;
    }

    return
        (
         (Calculate(imp, first + 1, last, !myTurn) + (myTurn ? imp[first] : 0))
         +
         (Calculate(imp, first, last - 1, !myTurn) + (myTurn ? imp[last] : 0))
        ) / 2;
}
```

My next approach would be to use similar code to work out the probability of each ship being yours in certain sizes of array, and then from that try to identify a pattern.

Edit: I've had a look at the probability of you getting each ship for different numbers of ships and I can't see any pattern emerging on first inspection. (Well, the odds of you getting the first ship looks like they're derived from [OEIS A001045](https://oeis.org/A001045), and the second from [A113954](https://oeis.org/A113954), but the third has no matches.) If I sat down and had a look at the maths I might be able to but this isn't looking like the direction expected of you on a programming test!

Comment: +1 A recursive function would have been my next approach as well. It's probably not possible to retrieve an exact average without it (though I might be proven wrong).

Comment: For turn #i if you take the corresponding row @i of Pascal's triangle and superimpose it on both sides off the array it provides the probability of each droid being hit on that turn. (Include the overlaps when they meet, as those droids could now be hit from either side.) Summing these weight for each odd-numbered row of Pascal's triangle will provide the EV for Player 1, but I have not had time to look for a closed-form for this evaluation. One would probably start by pre-calculating the necessary factorials in a look up table (only up to 50! needed as per specification.)